# Howto calculate first date of week and last date for week in python

Tags: python, datetime

I need Calculate dates for week in python

I need this

```
year = 2012
week = 23
(a,b) = func (year,week)
print a
print b

>>>2012-04-06
>>>2012-06-10
```

Could you help me ?

Comment: That's a long ass week

Comment: @Anthony, Did you forget a hypen, or this is just a [hobby](http://xkcd.com/37/) of a yours?

Comment: It is. @Jonatan, [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: Dates are complicated. http://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/days/ The first day of the week can depend on the locale and also the way the week number is determined

Comment: I think here you can find an answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30656008/get-start-date-and-end-date-of-the-week-given-week-number-and-year

Answer (score 13):

The date object contains a `weekday()` method.

This returns 0 for monday 6 for sunday.

(From googling) here is one solution: http://www.protocolostomy.com/2010/07/06/python-date-manipulation/ )

I think this can be made a little less verbose so here's my stab at it:

```
def week_magic(day):
    day_of_week = day.weekday()

    to_beginning_of_week = datetime.timedelta(days=day_of_week)
    beginning_of_week = day - to_beginning_of_week

    to_end_of_week = datetime.timedelta(days=6 - day_of_week)
    end_of_week = day + to_end_of_week

    return (beginning_of_week, end_of_week)
```

Comment: this is not in python but result is same                                                                    for i in `seq 0 52`; do echo "SELECT date('now', 'localtime',
        'start of year', '$(($i * 7)) days') AS ws, date('now', 'localtime',
        'start of year', '$(($i * 7 + 7)) days') AS we;";done | sqlite3 this will generate list of week limits for SQL and in second pass I will use it for sumarize in second SQL SELECT how I may send NEWLINE here????? enter is not working as ussual

Comment: week 1 2012-01-01 to 2012-01-07 
        week 2 2012-01-08 to 2012-01-14 
        week 3 2012-01-15 to 2012-01-21 
        week 4 2012-01-22 to 2012-01-28 
        week 5 2012-01-29 to 2012-02-04 
        week 6 2012-02-05 to 2012-02-11 
        week 7 2012-02-12 to 2012-02-18 
        week 8 2012-02-19 to 2012-02-25 
        week 9 2012-02-26 to 2012-03-03

Answer (score 6):

Little outdated answer, but there is a nice module called [isoweek](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/isoweek/) that really gets the trick done. To answer the original question you could do something like:

```
from isoweek import Week    

week = Week(2012, 23)
print(week.monday())
print(week.sunday())
```

Hope this helps anybody.

Answer (score 4):

I think @Anthony Sottile's answer should be this:

```
def week_magic(day):
    day_of_week = day.weekday()

    to_beginning_of_week = datetime.timedelta(days=day_of_week)
    beginning_of_week = day - to_beginning_of_week

    to_end_of_week = datetime.timedelta(days=6 - day_of_week)
    end_of_week = day + to_end_of_week

    return (beginning_of_week, end_of_week)
```

It works!

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer he is looking for is in datetime.isocalendar(datetime)
It returns a 3-tuple containing ISO year, week number, and weekday.

From any particular year (i.e '2015') one can determine the first day of the first week and then from there keep adding days using the timedelta function to find the particular week requested. With this information one can then return the first and last day of that week.