# Get start date and end date of the week, given week number and year

Tags: python

How do I get the start date and end date of the week, given week number and year in python?

I've tried this:

```
def get_start_end_dates(year, week):

     dlt = timedelta(days = (week - 1) * 7)
     d = date(year, 1, 1)
     return d + dlt, d + dlt + timedelta(days=6)
```

But with this function I assume that first week of the year starts with Monday.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304256/whats-the-best-way-to-find-the-inverse-of-datetime-isocalendar

Comment: The [Doomsday Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doomsday_rule) might be of interest to you. For example to calculate the "doomsday" for a certain year, you can just use the following function: ``doomsday = lambda y: (2 + 5*(y%4) + 4*(y%100) + 6*(y%400)) % 7``.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Howto calculate first date of week and last date for week in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10908499/howto-calculate-first-date-of-week-and-last-date-for-week-in-python)

Answer (score 4):

I have fixed your function:

```
def get_start_end_dates(year, week):
     d = date(year,1,1)
     if(d.weekday()<= 3):
         d = d - timedelta(d.weekday())             
     else:
         d = d + timedelta(7-d.weekday())
     dlt = timedelta(days = (week-1)*7)
     return d + dlt,  d + dlt + timedelta(days=6)
```

It gets the correct start and end day of the week in given year.

It also assumes that years with first day of the year on Friday, Saturday or Sunday have 1 week on next week. See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week

Comment: This solution is worth a lot! The code is working for Python 3.5.2

Comment: What if I want to get Sunday as the first day and Saturday as the last day?

Answer (score 4):

### Simplest (alternative) solution

First install the isoweek package

`pip install isoweek`

```
from isoweek import Week

w = Week(2021, 1)

print ("Week %s starts on %s" % (w, w.monday()))
print ("Week %s ends on %s" % (w, w.sunday()))
```

Output:

```
Week 2021W01 starts on 2021-01-04
Week 2021W01 ends on 2021-01-10
```

### Bonus:

#### If you need to apply this function to pandas dataframe

```
df["start_of_wk"] = df.apply(lambda x: Week(x['Year'], x['wk_of_the_year']).monday(), axis=1)

df["end_of_wk"] = df.apply(lambda x: Week(x['Year'], x['wk_of_the_year']).sunday(), axis=1)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import datetime
import time

 def getDateRangeFromWeek(p_year,p_week):

    firstdayofweek = datetime.datetime.strptime(f'{p_year}-W{int(p_week )- 1}-1', "%Y-W%W-%w").date()
    lastdayofweek = firstdayofweek + datetime.timedelta(days=6.9)
    return firstdayofweek, lastdayofweek


#Call function to get dates range 
firstdate, lastdate =  getDateRangeFromWeek('2019','2')

print('print function ',firstdate,' ', lastdate)
```