# How to get start of day given a week and year number by hive?

Tags: hive

## Goal:

I have table as below. I want to get start of day of each week in 2019. And the startday of week must be monday.

```
week 
23
24
25
26 
...
```

## Expected:

```
week   startofday
23     2019-06-03
..      ....
```

## Trying:

I had read `date_sub` and `date_add` but could not get what I want.

## Note:

My question is similar with this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30656008/get-start-date-and-end-date-of-the-week-given-week-number-and-year/30656058). The differ is the last is solved by python.

Comment: were you able to do this in Hive?

Answer (score 1):

I found the next useful example, on [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/222583/week-aggregation-in-hive.html) source and adapted for your purpose:

```
select 23 as weeknumber,
date_format(date_sub(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2018-12-29','yyyy-MM-dd')+(23*7*24*60*60)),pmod(datediff(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2018-12-29','yyyy-MM-dd')+(23*7*24*60*60)),'1900-01-07'),7)),"MMMMM dd,yyyy") as startday,
date_format(date_add(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2018-12-29','yyyy-MM-dd')+(23*7*24*60*60)),6 - pmod(datediff(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2018-12-29','yyyy-MM-dd')+(23*7*24*60*60)),"1900-01-07"),7)),"MMMMM dd,yyyy") as endday;
```

So, change the constant '23' with your column and 2018-12-28 with the end of the previous year that you need.

In a few words, the sql code makes this:

- takes the week:23, transforms it to seconds (23*7(days have a week)*24 hours*60mins*60seconds);
- transforms in seconds also the last day of last week of previous year (28-December-2018);
- addition the two sums and the result will be a date;
- having the date, we can calculate the first day of week (and last day, I know that you don't need it, but maybe someone will need it);

Now, in my example, because of my UTC, the first day of week is Sunday, not Monday as you expect!

Hope that it's what you need.

Results:
[image: results]

Comment: @F.Lazarescu This is not I want, it baesd on specific date but not the number of week.

Comment: @Jack, I just edited the answer. Please check again.

Comment: @F.Lazarescu I have columns of number not just one number.

Comment: Yes Jack, as I wrote you, instead of '23' put your column name and then, at the end, write ".. from your_table_name". It should work. Did you tried? If you have only weeks from 2019, you need to change only the constant '23'.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer Update:**
I was not able to do this with Hive available functions. had to write a UDF in Python.

datefunction.py:

```
import sys
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
try:
    for line in sys.stdin:
        week=line.strip()
        year="2019"
        newDate = datetime.strptime(year+week + ' 1', "%Y%W %w")
        my_date = newDate- timedelta(days=7)
        format_date = my_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

        sys.stdout.write('\t'.join([week,str(format_date)]) + '\n')

except:
    print(sys.exc_info())
```

Adding this udf to Hive:

```
add file /your udf location path/python/datefunction.py;
```

created a test_week table in Hive with column week datatype as int and entered few weeks data.

```
Results as below:

hive> select TRANSFORM (week) USING 'python datefunction.py' As (week,startofday) from db.test_week;
Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Status: Running (Executing on YARN cluster with App id application_1563337199692_13076)

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        VERTICES      STATUS  TOTAL  COMPLETED  RUNNING  PENDING  FAILED  KILLED
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Map 1 ..........   SUCCEEDED      1          1        0        0       0       0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
VERTICES: 01/01  [==========================>>] 100%  ELAPSED TIME: 0.83 s
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OK
23      2019-06-03
24      2019-06-10
25      2019-06-17
26      2019-06-24
27      2019-07-01
28      2019-07-08
29      2019-07-15
30      2019-07-22
31      2019-07-29
32      2019-08-05
```

Comment: get day out of date?

Comment: get start of day based on given week in a year

Comment: I could not validate your answer because I could not use udf. And I just want hive command to get the answer.

Comment: @Jack.. No issues. I did struggle to do it in Hive, finally used Python. :-)

Answer (score -1):

select next_day('2019-08-22', 'MONDAY');

Comment: select date_sub('2019-08-22',cast(date_format('2019-08-22','u') as int)-1);