# getting start and end of the week with Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using the query below to get the start and end of the week. Although **dayofweek** is part of the pyspark.sql.functions in this format within a SQL query it doesn't seem to recognize the function. I tried concatenating the function still it did not work. My main issue is that one timestamp listed is depending on the start and end of the week range to perform correctly and output the values I'm looking.

```
 somedataset.registerTempTable("mytable")
 spark.sql("SELECT DISTINCT max(col1) AS col1_edited, \
                               col2, col3, max(col4) AS col4_edited,\
                               min(MyTimestamp1) as MyTimestamp1_edited,\
                               date_sub(CAST(timestamp2 AS date), dayofweek-1) as week_start,\
                               date_sub(CAST(timestamp3 AS date), 7-dayofweek) as week_end,\
                               FROM mytabble \
                               GROUP BY col1_edited, col2, col3, col4, MyTimestamp1,\
                                        timestamp2,\
                                        timestamp3").registerTempTable("mineable")
```

I'm using Pyspark 3.1.1+amzn.0
any help will be greatly appreciated.
the output comes back it should look something like this:

[image]

UPDATE: based on the comment below this was the small fix (everything else remained the same.

```
date_sub(CAST(timestamp2 AS date), dayofweek(timestamp2)-1) as week_start,\
date_sub(CAST(timestamp3 AS date), 7-dayofweek(timestamp3)) as week_end,\
```

Comment: it's already been answered through below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62912383/fetch-week-start-date-and-week-end-date-from-date

Comment: I did try that approach and it did not work for me. though I'm currently checking a small change of what I posted if that worked as expected I'll post it.

Comment: no, I work directly on pyspark in Glue job and a Glue interactive session notebook for dev.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DAYOFWEEK` should be called with a column as an argument:

```
from datetime import date

_data = [
    (date(2023, 10, 13), ),
    (date(2023, 10, 16), ),
    (date(2023, 10, 28), ),
]
_schema = ['my_date']
df = spark.createDataFrame(_data, _schema)
df.createOrReplaceTempView('temp')
q = """
SELECT
  my_date,
  DATEADD(my_date, 1 - DAYOFWEEK(my_date)) AS WeekStart,
  DATEADD(my_date, 7 - DAYOFWEEK(my_date)) AS WeekEnd
FROM
  temp
"""
res = spark.sql(q)
res.show()

# +----------+----------+----------+
# |   my_date| WeekStart|   WeekEnd|
# +----------+----------+----------+
# |2023-10-13|2023-10-08|2023-10-14|
# |2023-10-16|2023-10-15|2023-10-21|
# |2023-10-28|2023-10-22|2023-10-28|
# +----------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: thank you so much, for the note: "DAYOFWEEK should be called with a column as an argument" I did not know this part. I got my solution in different form. Kind of similar to what I have initially but using your weekstart and weekend. I'll post it later. I got so immerse on solving the problem that I forgot to post the solution I got. but thank you again those 2 tips you are mentioning in your response is what I'm using :)